# control raspberry pi python project from other computer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi project that recognizes the faces in real time. I made a picture folder in the raspberry pi, which by adding new images to my system, can detect new people. My question now is:
1. How can i control these images from another computer (or a web interface or anything you suggest), which way i can add new images or delete images as desired?

Comment: You could put Dropbox on your Raspberry Pi. Then you can add and remove files from a folder your project watches by using any web-browser, smartphone, tablet or PC with Dropbox.

Comment: I dont have any information about Dropbox. Can you give me tutorials here about dropbox in raspberry pi?

Comment: Here maybe https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/dropbox-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Some of them are:

- [SSH](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)
- [VNC](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md)
- [SFTP](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/sftp.md) or [FTP](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md)

Or you can build a web server to control the items in the folders

Comment: But I don't want to allow users to access rpi directories. Just want to upload images to the directories that I specify.

Comment: it might be possible to use Python to make a custom client program and a server program with sockets

Comment: tnx,but i dont have any idea about websockets,I want to add different images to rcognize new people and login user and other things with the web service
How can I have such a web service?